# Why do I need to click 2 times on the button in order for the event to take place?

Tags: angular

I am making an app for user login. In this file, `AuthenticationService`, I communicate with the C# controller.

```js
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  readonly APIUrl = 'https://localhost:44309/api';

  isAuthorized:any;

  Login(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/Login', val);
  }

  Authorize(isAuthorized:boolean)
  {
    this.isAuthorized =  isAuthorized;
  }
}
```

In this file, `LoginComponent`, I call the `Login()` method in `AuthenticationService`, so the validation of the user details happens in the backend.

```js
export class InloginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth : AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }
  formModel = {
    Email: '',
    Password: ''
  }
  GebruikerList:any;
  geb:any;
  isAuthorized: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  Login()
  {
    this.geb={
      Email: this.formModel.Email,
      Wachtwoord: this.formModel.Password
    }
    this.Auth.Login(this.geb).subscribe(data => this.isAuthorized = data)
    this.Auth.Authorize(this.isAuthorized);

    if(this.isAuthorized) { this.router.navigate(['profile'])}
  }
}
```

---

After it's validated, it either returns `true` or `false`.
When it's `true`, it's supposed to take the user to the profile page. `Login()` is btw bound to the Login button. **The problem is, I have to click on the Login button twice (when the user's details are valid) to be taken to the page.** Why is that happening?

Comment: You have to put your `router` navigation line inside `data => ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flow seems correct, but change to this.
when you click the 2nd time, the isAuthorized gets true due to previous api response, hence clicking the 2nd time works
try this:

```
this.Auth.Login(this.geb).subscribe(data => {
    this.isAuthorized = data
    this.Auth.Authorize(this.isAuthorized);
    if(this.isAuthorized) { this.router.navigate(['profile'])}
}
```